# Capturing screenshot of Form and elements on form

Tags: c#, bitmap, screenshot

I'm trying to capture a screenshot of the MainWindow and content on the main window.  The MainWindow will sometimes be behind other elements and need to get screen capture without those other overlaying elements. This code currently returns a bitmap of the blank MainWindow form without any content.  The form has a bunch of different dynamic UI elements.  How can I take a current screenshot/capture of MainWindow and it's content?  Code for the MainWindow content is waay to long to post so I hope that this is enough.

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();
bounds.Width = Program.MainWindow.Width;
bounds.Height = Program.MainWindow.Height;

screenShot = new Bitmap(Program.MainWindow.Width,
                       Program.MainWindow.Height,
                       PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
Program.MainWindow.DrawToBitmap(screenShot, bounds);
```

Comment: have you tried `CopyFromScreen()` member of the `graphics` class?

Comment: Yes but I get a black bitmap from that

Comment: Ok, just got CopyFromScreen() to work but I want it to capture the MainWindow form only and not the two other forms which will be open in the process when the screenshot is take.  Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer below. It should use the location of your main form, assuming that is what `Program.MainWindow` indicates. If the solution solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: @Yuval why did you delete your post, I was posting the answer !

Comment: @meda because I figured the answer out and it wasn't an issue with the code I had posted.  Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it by using the `CopyFromScreen` method of the `Graphics` class

```
        Rectangle bounds = Program.MainWindow.Bounds;
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        }
        b.Save("YOUR FILE NAME HERE");
```

Comment: This captures the screenshot of the bounds but I want a screenshot of the MainWindow which in some cases will be in the background.

Comment: If it is in the background you won't be able to take a shot of it. It has to be up in the foreground, otherwise there is nothing for it to copy. You might be able to get around it by using the graphics object of the form, but even that isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: This half fixed the issue.  I ended up iterating through the open form elements on top of the mainwindow and setting their opacity to 0, then doing CopyFromScreen and re-setting their opacity to 1.  I know it's not a great way to do this and I'm sure there is a better way, but for now this works.  Thanks for the help.